# Is Savage Worlds Deluxe Edition the new standard rules?

Tags: savage-worlds

I'm not clear about what role the [*Savage Worlds Deluxe edition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savage_Worlds) serves now. Are future Savage Worlds products from Pinnacle going to be released using the Deluxe rules from now on? Or will they continue to be using the Explorer's Edition rules and the Deluxe rules are a standalone book of options (similar to D&D's *[Unearthed Arcana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unearthed_Arcana#Dungeons_.26_Dragons_3rd_edition)*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is basically Yes. The Deluxe is meant to be round up of all the corrections from the Explorer's Edition plus expositions of the rules and some new stuff. There will be a new smaller paper back of the Deluxe edition, without the expositions <strike>, but as is normal from Pinnacle we don't know when this will be .</strike>

Correction - [Savage Worlds Deluxe: Explorer’s Edition](https://www.peginc.com/store/savage-worlds-deluxe-explorers-edition/) now available.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't heard about the plan for the smaller version. That will be the official rule book then. Right?

Comment: http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31906 Sometime in Aug '12 (may be) there will be an soft back version SWD:EE. I think both are intended as the official book.